# Database Table Structure Optimization

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to minimize MySQL DB query times. Here's my situation.... I have the following tables:

- Stores Table

  - ID Field
  - Name Field
  - Location Field
- Shelves Table

  - ID Field
  - Store ID Field
  - Name Field
- ShelfItems Table

  - ID Field
  - Shelves ID Field
  - Item ID Field
  - Item Name Field
  - Position Field
  - Rating Field

When my program (built in C++) starts up it loads all the stores from the DB into their own object & stores them in a list.

It then stores all the shelves from the DB into their own objects (each Store can have anywhere from 0 to 10 Shelves), and assign them to the appropriate store object.

Finally, it loads ALL the ShelfItems from the DB into their own objects, and assigns them to the appropriate Shelf object. Each Shelf object can hold anywhere from 0 to 130 ShelfItems.

Then when the software closes, it re-saves ALL the Stores, then all the Shelves, then all the ShelfItems.

My problem is that there can be LOTS of Save & Load requests happening at once, which can leads to longer than expected query times. So I'm trying to optimize this a bit.

Would serializing shelves & shelf items into a string and storing it as a column in the Stores table be faster on read/writes?

The result would make the Stores table look more like this...

- Stores Table

  - ID Field
  - Name Field
  - Location Field
  - Serialized Shelves Field (would contain both Shelves & their ShelfItems)

Comment: The whole point of a relational database is so that you don't have to write everything at once.  Only write things that have changed and only when they actually change.

Answer (score 0):

That (storing in a String) is usually a bad idea, or when it is a good idea - using a NoSQL solution tends to be a better idea. I am not sure how you app is used but presumably ALL ShelfItems do not need to be considered all at once, you would then usually look into Lazy Loading to only load the items when they are needed. A middle ground of this approach is to preload frequently used items or batches. This can be facilitated with the use of a Cache, but this can bring a bunch of other consideration such as when to refresh the data. You should also only update items which have changed to prevent some of the saving...

Comment: There's no choice as to how it loads or saves. The only change I can make is what I mentioned above... I just want to know if it would be faster.

Comment: So you can only modify the database but no the application? That doesn't really make sense as you would have to change the application to use the new database schema in your proposed change?

Comment: The system is already using a cache, and it already only updates when it needs to be updated. What I'm saying is that the optimization needs to be on the DB level.

Comment: ,,,,, You literally said: "Then when the software closes, it re-saves ALL the Stores, then all the Shelves, then all the ShelfItems.". No your proposed database change will not help performance, in fact it is a bad idea. If your application already uses a cache and only saved changed fields, why do you think merging columns in your DB will be any faster?

Comment: Because we had a similar system in place for a smaller version of the above mentioned diagram, and the bottleneck only happens when we get to this point.

Comment: Key word - 'smaller'. You need to revisit your design. Saving/Loading ALL data will always be slow. You have to be clever about it.... We can't help if you argue any suggestions. Please go read up

Comment: Hopefully this is for student project and not a real production app